# IBM i (iSeries) Power 7 - WinSQL

Tags: ibm-midrange, winsql

I am having an sudden issue, I have a IBM Power 7 iseries AS/400 server, I just store my database here, the development team works with Genexus and from yesterday we are unable to create tables (for example) in the server not even running the commands directly in the iseries box, we have rebooted the box twice, we have looked for logs and nothing, the winsql software we use only reports a Error:

> SQL0901 - Error del sistema SQL. (State:S1000, Native Code: FFFFFC7B)

Can anyone help me out with this? or how to follow up on this, we have been using this IBM power 7 iseries for 3 years....

Comment: I have tried this statement befor and worked perfectly: CREATE TABLE DESARROLLO.ParametroUsuario (UsuarioId DECIMAL( 10) NOT NULL , ParametroUsuarioId DECIMAL( 10) NOT NULL , ParametroUsuarioDesc varchar(128) NOT NULL , ParametroUsuarioVal varchar(512) , PRIMARY KEY(UsuarioId, ParametroUsuarioId, ParametroUsuarioDesc)) suddently it just pops the error SQL0901... thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask the IBM i admin if they put on any PTFs (IBM fixes).  When you say 'Running the commands directly on the iseries box' how are you doing that?  STRSQL?

Answer (score 2):

SQL0901 is a generic message.  The QZDASOINIT joblog will have more details.

See [ODBC diagnostic and performance tools](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaii/rzaiiodbc62.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[Some possibly helpful information regarding the msg SQL0901](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/_tJJl3YAks4/UffZV8Kmx5sJ)

My SWAG for the scenario is that there is an error with the System Database Cross Reference (DBXREF) giving rise to the error, and the preceding error(s) [logged in the joblog of the job servicing the SQL CREATE request] will diagnose that condition; the table likely can be created using a *short* name [for the TABLE and the CONSTRAINT], or the TABLE with CONSTRAINT may be able to be created into a different library.  If such a condition is the origin, then some diagnostic information could be collected [e.g. dumps of objects tracking the *DBXREF feature and history logs] followed by the recovery action of reclaiming [a portion of] the DBXREF data [for the specific library exhibiting the error].